# How to get location while dragging MKPinAnnotation on map

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I am trying to show magnifier glass effect on Iphone map when user drag the `MKPinAnnotation` object. The requirement is when user move pin at that time I want to display map area below the finger.

For that I have an idea that I will show that part of map in another map view. For this purpose I used:

```
pinAnnotation.draggable = YES;
```

When user pick up the pin I get `MKAnnotationViewDragStateStarting` in delegate method.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view didChangeDragState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)newState fromOldState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)oldState {
}
```

But when user move the pin over the map.. this method is not being invoke continuously. I was in impression that this method will continuously get called with `MKAnnotationViewDragStateDragging` and I will get coordinates accordingly.

1. Why this method is not being called when pin point is being dragged.
2. Is there any other way to achieve such requirement.
3. How can I get coordinates when user drag the pin point.

Thanks

Comment: To answer question 1 it is not being called while being dragged because the state is not changing. It _changes_ once to dragging and once from dragging, but can't continuously _change_ to the same value.

Comment: Thanks @Craig I got it from your comment that this can't be called multiple time with same value.

Comment: Found any solution to this yet? I setup a loop that run every 0.5s to check the view's coord but that doesn't work too as the coord doesn't change until the drag end.

Comment: I have the same question.Now is for iOS 12. Does anyone have solution.